# Serialize Object

Tags: c#

I am new to serialization and I cannot for the life of me figure out how to fix this exception I am getting...

I have an object that has the following structure

```
[XmlRoot("MaxCut2")]
public class MaxCut2File : IFile
{
    public MaxCut2File()
    {
        MyJob = new Job();
        Job.Reference = "MyRef";
    }

    [XmlElement("JobDetails", typeof(Job))]
    public IJob MyJob
    {
        get;
        set;
    }    
}
```

An inteferface...

```
   public interface IJob
    {        
        string Reference { get; set; }
    }
```

And an class

```
[Serializable()]
public class Job : IJob
{
    [XmlElement("Reference")]
    public string Reference { get; set; }
}
```

When I try to serialize an instance of the MaxCut2File object I get an error

{"Cannot serialize member 'MaxCut2File.MaxCut2File.MyJob' of type 'MaxCut2BL.Interfaces.IJob', see inner exception for more details."}
"There was an error reflecting type 'MaxCut2File.MaxCut2File'."

However if I change my property MyJob from the IJob type to the Job type it works fine...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a little trick You might give a try :

[Serializing an interface](https://web.archive.org/web/20200203182350/http://geekswithblogs.net:80/SoftwareDoneRight/archive/2008/01/16/how-to-serialize-an-interface-using-the-xmlserializer.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot serialize an interface. How would the serializer know which type will be used? You simply said there's an interface.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding:

```
public interface IJob : ISerializable
```